# What is the maximum size of symbol data type in KDB+?

Tags: kdb

I cannot find the maximum size of the symbol data type in KDB+.

Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Do you mean (a) max amount of unique symbols allowed or (b) max amount of characters in one symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If youa re talking the physical length of a symbol, well symbols exist as interred strings in kdb, so the maximum string length limit would apply. As strings are just a [list of characters](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/3_Lists/#325-simple-char-lists-and-strings) in kdb, the maximum size of a string would be the maximum length of a list. In [3.x](https://code.kx.com/v2/releases/ChangesIn3.0/) this would be 2<sup>64</sup> - 1, In previous versions of kdb this limit was 2,000,000,000.

**However** there is a 2TB maximum serialized size limit that would likely kick in first, you can roughly work out the size of a sym by serializing it,

```
q)count -8!`
10
q)count -8!`a
11
q)count -8!`abc
13
```

So each character adds a single byte, this would give a roughly **10<sup>12</sup>** character length size limit

If you mean the maximum amount of symbols that can exist in memory, then the limit is 1.4B.